# Change whole cell color on selected date fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar and I change the background color of the selected date. My problem now is, if the date is the current date, not all of the cells are of the selected date's color, half of them have today's color code and half are having the selected cell color.

The selected date is green and current date is yellow. Here is my css code:

```
.fc-event-container {
  display: none;
}
.fc-day-top {
  border-color: solid green 3px;
}
.fc-today {
  background: #ffffa1 !important;
}
.fc-highlight {
  background: green !important;
}
.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton td, .fc-row .fc-helper-skeleton td {
  border-color: inherit !important;
}
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('#calendars').fullCalendar({

    height: 395,

    header: {
      // title, prev, next, prevYear, nextYear, today
      left: 'prev',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'next'
    },
    events: [
  {
      title  : 'event1',
      start  : '2019-03-01'
  },
  {
      title  : 'event2',
      start  : '2019-03-05',
  },
  {
      title  : 'event3',
      start  : '2019-03-15'
  },
  {
    title  : 'event5',
    start  : '2019-05-15'
  }

],
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
    // like that
    var eventStart = moment(event.start);
    $("td[data-date='"+eventStart.format('YYYY-MM-DD')+"']").addClass('dayWithEvent');
},

 
    // 選択可
    selectable: true,
    // 選択時にプレースホルダーを描画
    selectHelper: true,

  })
})
```

```css
.fc-event-container {
  display: none;
}
.fc-day-top {
  border-color: solid green 3px;
}
.fc-today {
  background: #ffffa1 !important;
}
.fc-highlight {
  background: green !important;
}
.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton td, .fc-row .fc-helper-skeleton td {
  border-color: inherit !important;
}
.dayWithEvent {
  background: #b0e0e6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.change-bg {
  background-color : green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.min.css" defer/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.min.js" defer></script>
<div id="calendars"></div>
```

Comment: Please add a fiddle demo

Comment: @NIshamMahsin Please see update,

Comment: @AndyHoffman Please see update

Comment: anyone has an idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

Just got it! I just added this css:

```
td.fc-day-top.fc-today.fc-state-highlight {
   display: block;
}
```

And now it blocks all cell. :)

Comment: Good! it is recommended that you mark your answer as accepted to let other users know which answer worked for you

Comment: @Gouda Yes I will tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

The fullCalendar() function highlights current date by default as a built-in feature.
So, when you set the bg color manually it overlaps with the default color.

I have just removed the below snippet from your code, and it worked fine

```
.fc-today {
  background: #ffffa1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it has no problem with me if it is default, the problem is my client for they want it to be yellow. Thanks.